# scope issue Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a JS Function that looks like so:

```
<JQUERY IS INCLUDED HERE>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ll = jQuery.noConflict();
    function tongle_bill_address(hide){
        if(hide){
            ll('#popUpDiv').hide();
            ll('#blanket').hide();
        }
        else{
            ll('#popUpDiv').show();
            ll('#blanket').show();
        }
    }
</script>
```

And further down the page I have:

```
<input name="billingSameAsShipping" value="no" id="radioTwo" onchange="tongle_bill_address(0);" type="radio"/>
```

Now I am well aware of simply doing something like `$('#ELEMENT_ID').click(function(){});` and even how to use `.toggle()` However I am still confused as to why I am outside of the scope with trying to call this function via `onchange`?

Final Error Message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tongle_bill_address is not defined
```

Comment: Is this really the exact code you have? I cannot see anything wrong with it. There are only two reasons why you would get that error: (a) `tongle_bill_address` is not global, e.g. it is defined inside the `$(document).ready` event handler. (b) You have a syntax error in its definition or in the code before it (and hence it is never created). See, it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/fFcaB/.

Comment: other then the fact that the jquery include is located much much higher then this piece of code yes it is.

Comment: Load the code in doc.ready `jQuery(function($){...})`

Comment: @elclanrs – document.ready is not a panacea! In fact, since it will scope the function to the anonymous function, it will make certain that it **won't** work!

Comment: Can you try to create a jsFiddle to demonstrate your problem? Here is one that demonstrates that your code works! http://jsfiddle.net/WrNRr/

Comment: @Quentin: Well, that would be the answer to the next question. "My code doesn't work!". Answer: "Use jQuery to add the event". Or add the scripts at the end.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to do things this way (I would recommend not) - ensure that the function is being defined in the HTML above where you a referencing it.

Comment: It's unlikely that a user can interact with the page before the DOM was completely loaded. The function is only called when the user selects the radio button, i.e. after the whole page was rendered.